# Bind collection in java driver for arangoDB

Tags: java, arangodb

I'm using java driver for ArangoDB. 
I have an array of JSONs in a String variable and I want it to be inserted in table. I use the following query

```
for r in @fromCollection insert r into @targetCollection
```

In web interface insert goes well, but in Java I'm facing troubles with binding these 2 variables -

```
1553 - ERROR_QUERY_BIND_PARAMETER_TYPE
Will be raised when a bind parameter has an invalid value or type
```

Can you help me with binding collection names as variables in ArangoDB?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the below as the answer, and if it isn't, comment as to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how your JSON String variable plays a role in this query.

When you want to insert the JSON documents included in your String variable you can use the method `importDocuments(String)` for that:

```
ArangoDB arango = new ArangoDB.Builder().build();
arango.db().collection("myCollection").importDocuments(jsonArray);
```

Related to your problem with your query:

A special type of bind parameter exists for injecting collection names. This type of bind parameter has a name prefixed with an additional `@` symbol (thus when using the bind parameter in a query, two `@` symbols must be used). For more information about bind parameters take a look [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Fundamentals/BindParameters.html)

Your query has to look:

```
 for r in @@fromCollection insert r into @@targetCollection
```

In Java it looks as follow:

```
ArangoDB arango = new ArangoDB.Builder().build();
Map<String, Object> bindVars = new HashMap<>();
bindVars.put("@fromCollection", "...");
bindVars.put("@toCollection", "...");
arango.db().query("for r in @@fromCollection insert r into @@targetCollection", bindVars, null, BaseDocument.class)
```